# Checkbox button looks weird mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox, when I check mobile view on my browser using chrome developer tools it looks fine :

Mobile view on chrome dev tools
[image: Mobile view on chrome dev tools]

but once I check it on my actual phone the checkbox looks like the following:
[image: on my actual iphone]

Updated screenshot of the code :

updated HTML code that comes from a snippet
[image: updated HTML code that comes from a snippet]

CSS code
[image: updated HTML code that comes from a snippet]

Comment: add your running sample code to help better way.

Comment: Some code would be nice. This probably isn't default behavior, so it's likely something in your code. Could you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: I'm using a help desk solution platform so the code comes from a snippet. I've updated the answer with a screenshot from the dev tools the thing is that it looks good when i check it on my computer even on mobile view so I'm not sure this screenshot would be useful.

Comment: i'm trying to find a way to inspect the code on my iphone

Comment: @NetaYamin in order to inspect your iphone from your pc [here](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/), I think it should help you solve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).